# WPF binding does not work if function is triggered by a button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If the function is triggered by a Button the databinding doen't not work. If I call the same function on the MainWindow init it works. Anyone has any idea how to fix it?
If I click on the button in debug mode I can clearly see that the SampleString property has changed as expected. Why can't I see the change in the TextBlock?

Mainwindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;


namespace DTC_client_WPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public string SampleString { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            SampleString = string.Empty;
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            Button_Click(null, null);
        }
        private void Print(string str)
        {
            SampleString += DateTime.Now + "|" + str + "\n";
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Print("Clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DTC_client_WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DTC_client_WPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock x:Name="WPFConsole" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="Black" Foreground="GreenYellow" Text="{Binding Path=SampleString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Button Content="RUN" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="51" Width="76" FontSize="16" Click="Button_Click" Foreground="Black" Background="#FFB02626" BorderThickness="4,4,4,4"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is the result no matter how often do I click on the "RUN" button.
[image: MainWindow result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bindings in WPF work through the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and its `PropertyChanged` event. If this event is not fired and not implemented by the DataContext, then the binding engine will not get notified the value was changed.

Comment: Okay, but why does it gets fired when I call Button_Click(null, null) in the MainWindow init and why doesn't it work when I push the button? The same function is being called.

Comment: No it doesn't. Where do you raise the `PropertyChanged` event?

Comment: If it won't get fired then why do I see this-> http://prntscr.com/vqs9wp  ? I can see that the text "2020.11.26.21:15:10|Clicked" was added once. How is this possible then? Shouldn't I see an empty TextBlock then?

Comment: You see the first "click" because that is called in the constructor of the window, and hence the SampleString value is set before the data binding is established. The additional click events will update SampleString (a tool such as WPFSnoop will confirm this) but there is no mechanism to update the bound control. Your MainWindow class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and your SampleString property needs to trigger the PropertyChanged event each time it is updated.